# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: git, error-handling

I am trying to run "./resumeio2pdf [https://resume.io/r/LAQQvpJgs"](https://resume.io/r/LAQQvpJgs%22) this command but getting an error as "'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,". Could you please help

I tried to change to folder location but I didn't work.

Comment: What has this to do with Git?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/sopov/resumeio2pdf), `resumeio2pdf` is a [Go program](https://go.dev/), which means you can try and install it with [`go install`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies):

> Install compiles and installs the packages named by the import paths.
>
> Executables are installed in the directory named by the `GOBIN` environment variable, which defaults to `$GOPATH/bin` or `$HOME/go/bin` if the `GOPATH` environment variable is not set.
> Executables in `$GOROOT` are installed in `$GOROOT/bin` or `$GOTOOLDIR` instead of `$GOBIN`.

```
go install github.com/sopov/resumeio2pdf@latest
```

As long as your `$HOME/go/bin` is in your `$PATH`, `resumeio2pdf` will be recognize: no need for `./resumeio2pdf` (which would look for a `resumeio2pdf` executable in the current folder).